# jQuery Dropdown Navigation

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

I've written some jQuery code that works, but I'm a novice in jQuery and I want to know how to improve my code if possible.

I know I have 3 near identical blocks of code. If I create a function, the code will be the same. I'm looking for more accurate code and am trying to reduce my code into fewer lines.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/968pA/6/)

```
    $('#click-me-idiomas').click(function () {
        var idiomasVisible = $("#menu-idiomas").is(":visible");
        var coleccionesVisible = $("#menu-colecciones").is(":visible");
        var nosotrosVisible = $("#menu-nosotros").is(":visible");
        if (coleccionesVisible || nosotrosVisible) {
            if (coleccionesVisible) {
                $('#click-me-colecciones').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-idiomas').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-colecciones").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-idiomas').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
            if (nosotrosVisible) {
                $('#click-me-nosotros').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-idiomas').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-nosotros").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-idiomas').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (idiomasVisible) {
                $("#menu-idiomas").slideToggle('slow', function () {
                    $('#click-me-idiomas').removeClass('active');
                });
            } else {
                $('#click-me-idiomas').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-idiomas").slideToggle('slow');
            }
        }

    });

    $('#click-me-colecciones').click(function () {
        var idiomasVisible = $("#menu-idiomas").is(":visible");
        var coleccionesVisible = $("#menu-colecciones").is(":visible");
        var nosotrosVisible = $("#menu-nosotros").is(":visible");
        if (idiomasVisible || nosotrosVisible) {
            if (idiomasVisible) {
                $('#click-me-idiomas').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-colecciones').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-idiomas").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-colecciones').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
            if (nosotrosVisible) {
                $('#click-me-nosotros').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-colecciones').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-nosotros").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-colecciones').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (coleccionesVisible) {
                $("#menu-colecciones").slideToggle('slow', function () {
                    $('#click-me-colecciones').removeClass('active');
                });
            } else {
                $('#click-me-colecciones').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-colecciones").slideToggle('slow');
            }
        }

    });

    $('#click-me-nosotros').click(function () {
        var idiomasVisible = $("#menu-idiomas").is(":visible");
        var coleccionesVisible = $("#menu-colecciones").is(":visible");
        var nosotrosVisible = $("#menu-nosotros").is(":visible");
        if (idiomasVisible || coleccionesVisible) {
            if (idiomasVisible) {
                $('#click-me-idiomas').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-nosotros').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-idiomas").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-nosotros').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
            if (coleccionesVisible) {
                $('#click-me-colecciones').removeClass('active');
                $('#click-me-nosotros').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-colecciones").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $('#menu-nosotros').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (nosotrosVisible) {
                $("#menu-nosotros").slideToggle('slow', function () {
                    $('#click-me-nosotros').removeClass('active');
                });
            } else {
                $('#click-me-nosotros').addClass('active');
                $("#menu-nosotros").slideToggle('slow');
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written in my way. You can see it with this link http://jsfiddle.net/968pA/8/ .

HTML :

```
<header id="masthead" class="container site-header" role="banner">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" id="click-me-languages" data-toggle="menu-languages">LANGUAGES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="click-me-books" data-toggle="menu-books">BOOKS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="click-me-about" data-toggle="menu-about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-list" id="menu-languages">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">English</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Spanish</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Français</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Deutsch</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-list" id="menu-books">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Book #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Book #2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Book #3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Book #4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Book #5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-list" id="menu-about">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (same as original) :

```
* { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
a {text-decoration:none;}
.container { padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; margin:0 auto; max-width:1170px; }
.col-3 { width:285px; }

.col-3 {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.site-header { background-color:#00AF85; }
.site-header li { display:inline; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; line-height:70px; padding-right:18px; }
.site-header a { color:#fff; }
.site-header a:hover,
.site-header a.active { color:#403F41; }

#menu-languages,
#menu-books,
#menu-about { background-color:#fff; display:none; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:700; text-transform:uppercase; }

#menu-languages .col-12, #menu-books .col-12, #menu-about .col-12 { height:50px; }

#menu-languages li, #menu-books li, #menu-about li { padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px; }
#menu-languages a, #menu-books a, #menu-about a { line-height:20px; }

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

JS :

```
function getActiveLink() {
    var $activeLink = $('#masthead').find('a.active:first');
    return ($activeLink.length > 0)? $activeLink: null;
}

function getActiveMenu() {
    var $activeMenu = $('.menu-list:visible:first');
    return ($activeMenu.length > 0)? $activeMenu: null;
}

$('#click-me-languages, #click-me-books, #click-me-about').click(function (event) {
    var $thisLink = $(event.currentTarget);
    var menu = $thisLink.data('toggle');
    var $thisMenu = $('#' + menu);
    var $activeLink = getActiveLink();
    var $activeMenu = getActiveMenu();
    if ($thisMenu.is($activeMenu)) {
        $activeLink.removeClass('active');
        $activeMenu.slideUp('slow');
    }else if ($activeMenu === null) {
        $thisLink.addClass('active');
        $thisMenu.slideDown('slow');        
    }else {
        $activeMenu.slideUp('slow', function() {
            $activeLink.removeClass('active');
            $thisLink.addClass('active');
            $thisMenu.slideDown('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

I tried to remove duplicated code and merge the events to one, So I need to get  menu and link that being active, then I can do whatever to the menu and the link. My code isn't the best but I think you can learn from it. I added class to div menus and added data-toggle to links so that I can get active link and active menu easier.

Comment: Links can go away or [temporarily fail](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2015/41243). Please add the code to your answer.

Comment: I like it, but: there doesn't seem to be much point in adding the `data-toggle`. It could be renamed to something more meaningful (`data-menu-id`?), or it could be removed altogether. In the latter case, replace with `var menu = $thisLink.attr("id").substr("click-me-".length);`. In fact, the `menu` variable is used only once, and it isn't a complicated calculation, nor does it really add clarity to the code. The expression could be pasted directly into the selector: `var $thisMenu = $("#menu-" + $thisLink.attr("id").substr("click-me-".length));`.

Comment: Kamonwat Sangudsub thanks a lot!!!! And Schism, thanks to you too. I will take your tip and I will put it on the code :)